# php - Error text:Unknown column ' ' in field list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I can't figure out what it is wrong with the below line of code as I'm getting the following error in php server:

**Error happened on query "INSERT INTO polygon (`name`, `polygons`) VALUES (population_data_per_block.1, GeomFromText(@g))" Error text:Unknown column 'population_data_per_block.1' in 'field list'**

```
return array ($query , 'INSERT INTO ' . polygon . ' (`name`, `polygons`) VALUES (' . $polygon["name"] . ', GeomFromText(@g))');
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters to pass values into queries, and you won't have problems like this.

Comment: You need to surround your values with quotes (at least when they're string/varchar). Also careful of potential SQL injections if you don't control what `$polygon` contains. Better to use prepared statements whenever possible.

Comment: @Jeto I have tried to include them but unsuccessfully

Comment: Well that should fix that error unless you're doing it wrong. What database API are you using? Again, it would still be better to use prepared statements.

Comment: @Jeto I am using MySQL

Comment: I'm going to guess mysqli then... http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: You don't seem to have accepted any answers yet (I answered another of your questions and you deleted it once you had an answer).  Is there a problem with the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the command `fetchColumn` or `fetchAll`.

Answer (score 0):

i am using php pdo.

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO polygon (name, polygons) VALUES (:name, :polygons)') ;
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':name' => $polygon["name"],
                ':polygons' => 'GeomFromText(@g)' //i don't know what is GeomFromText(@g)

            ));
```